# Prove $\frac{2a + b}{3} ∈ (a, b)$ for all real numbers where $0 < a < b$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, proof-writing

I can prove it using numbers, but obviously that can't solve for every real number.

How do I properly prove this?

Comment: Start with $0<a<b$ and manipulate this inequality until you have $(2a+b)/3$ in the middle: $...<(2a+b)/3<...$.

Comment: Can you prove that $3a<2a+b<3b$?

Comment: Hint:  $a < b$ so $2a + a < 2a + b$.

Comment: I see you are all arriving to the same-ish conclusion, and a now-deleted answer did help understand a little. So I understand that getting to **3a < 2a + b < 3b** is kind of the "goal" to prove, but how does that actually prove it? Maybe I'm overthinking it.

Answer (score 4):

$$
\frac{2a+b}{3} < \frac{2b + b}{3} = b
$$

$$
\frac{2a+b}{3} > \frac{2a + a}{3} = a
$$

Answer (score 0):

I will give a very short, general proof here.
This is a special case of a **weighted arithmetic mean**: $$\displaystyle\overline x= \frac{\sum_{i=0}^{N}n_ix_i}{\sum_{i=0}^{N}n_i}$$ where $n_i$ is the weight(read: coefficient) given to $x_i$.

 Now, let $x_k$ be the largest of all the $x_i$. Then for any i, $n_ix_i<n_ix_k$. And so $$\displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^{N}n_ix_i< \sum_{i=0}^{N}n_ix_k = x_k\sum_{i=0}^{N}n_i$$ Thus, $\overline x = \frac{\sum_{i=0}^{N}n_ix_i}{\sum_{i=0}^{N}n_i} < x_k$ where $x_k$ is the largest element of all the $x_i$’s.

In your case, N=2, $x_1=a, x_2=b, n_1=2, n_2=1$. Hence proved.